# Need to override django auto_now_add in pytest factory

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

Due to **auto_now_add** in django models **sent_at** is not working in pytest factory. Need to overrive sent_at for pytest factory

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="xx")
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="yy")
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class ABCFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    x = factory.SubFactory(XFactory)
    y = factory.SubFactory(YFactory)
    sent_at = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(seconds=40)
```

Comment: Can't you make use of the *freezegun*: https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe checkout this solution posted in the factory_boy github:
https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/102

In short, there are 2 solutions:

- Remove the `auto_now_add` in your model field and instead use `default=timezone.now`. It will be fairly similar, except the field wont be read-only in the admin. But now you can easily override/update it
- Override the `_create` method so that it sets the field and re-save the instance AFTER it was initially created

Comment: The first solution is definitely the better one.

Comment: I think so too. Way simpler, does not over-complicate things.